# Postgis, Update Geometry Column With Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, geometry, postgis

Hello 
i got a strange behavior. 
Postgres 12

POSTGIS="2.5.4" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3" PROJ="Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020" GDAL="GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28" LIBXML="2.9.7" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.0" RASTER

Java Postgis Dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code is:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
((org.postgresql.PGConnection) connection).addDataType("geometry", PGgeometry.class);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute("UPDATE COORDINATES SET location = 'SRID=4326;POINT(13.3664665 52.573673)' where id = 1");
```

This results in following error:

```
ERROR: function st_makepoint(double precision, double precision) does not exist
```

But when i execute the update statement directly on psql it works fine. 
Any other statements which do not include geometry columns also working fine.

Anyone got a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean to say when you run `UPDATE COORDINATES SET location = 'SRID=4326;POINT(13.3664665 52.573673)' where id = 1` directly, it updates correctly with no errors?

Comment: yes, running this update in dbeaver works correctly without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue.
There is a trigger on this column.
Dont know yet why theres a difference between java commit and dbeaver commit, but the trigger is the culprit.